# Python random.choice

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does anyone have an idea of how I can use random.choice on a python dictionary to choose a key from the dictionary.

Also, how do I integrate an if statement that checks whether the value that is entered from raw_input is assigned to the key that is randomly chosen?

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? You have two separate problems, how about trying to solve each one separately *then* combine them?

Comment: *Edit the question*, you donut; indentation matters in Python, how can we read it in comments?!

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. I included my example. I hope it is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
my_dict = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3', 'key4': 'val4'}
rand_key = random.choice(my_dict.keys())
user_input = raw_input('Guess...')

if user_input == my_dict[rand_key]:
    print 'You guessed it!'
else:
    print 'Better luck next time!'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.